# Set an element in each row & column that cannot cross each other (think of chess)

Tags: php

I have a table of 6 by 6, and Im trying to set 6 elements inside that table that cannot cross each other (think of chess). Im terrible with math and these thing to not sure if there's an easy way to build something?

In my example below the variables totalElements & $match do nothing but should set 6 elements.

```
        $size = 6;
        $totalElements = 6
        echo '<table>';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $size; $i++) {
            echo '<tr>';
            for ($ii = 1; $ii <= $size; $ii++) {
                echo '<td>';
                // $match should set an element
                // this element can not be crossed vertical, 
                // horizontal or diagonal
                // $totalElements = number of elements that must be set
                if($match && $totalElements){
                    echo '<div>X</div>';
                }
                echo '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: _trying to set 6 elements inside that table that cannot cross each other (think of chess)_ Can you elaborate?

Comment: Think of the Queen 8 (I think its called this)

Comment: So, you are trying to solve N Queens problem in PHP?(here, N = 6)

Comment: Yes im trying to build something like that

Comment: Ok, so are you familiar with backtracking concept in Algorithms?

Comment: Is this thread helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998153/algorithm-of-n-queens

Comment: No im terrible with Algorithms :-(

Comment: I request you to learn that because otherwise, even a well written solution will become difficult to comprehend.

Comment: Why not do that manually? like just go straight to the table instead of attempting to do this with PHP...

Comment: Its an asignment, and i cant find a lot useable basic stuff about php backtracking (for dummies)

Comment: Does you assignment prohibit you from just using an array and echo the solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create chess board game or something like this.
you can follow this code

```php
 echo '<table>';
        for($row=1;$row<=6;$row++)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            for($col=1;$col<=6;$col++)
            {
                $total=$row+$col;
                if($total%2==0){
                echo "<td style='background:blue'>X</td>";
                }else{
                echo "<td style='background:red'>Y</td>";
                }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
      }
        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Lol, no the background patern is not needed 

Comment: so this is Ok or not ?

Comment: No this is not what I was looking for